# Python, How to remove gaps between text and variable?

Tags: python, random, formatting

So I wanted to create an IP randomizer but cannot find out how to make it so the number comes out as x.x.x.x instead of x . x . x . x

Code:

```
randomnum = random.randint(1,255)
randomnum2 = random.randint(1,255)
randomnum3 = random.randint(1,255)
randomnum4 = random.randint(1,255)
print('Random IP = "%d"' % randomnum % '. "%d"' % randomnum2 % '. "%d"' % randomnum3 % '. "%d"' % randomnum4 % '. "%d"')
```

Comment: Remove the spaces in between your periods and `%d`

Comment: But better practice would be to use `random_ip = '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(num1, num2, num3, num4)`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string formating is wrong.

```
print('Random IP = "{}.{}.{}.{}"'.format(randomnum, randomnum4, randomnum3, randomnum4))
```